# Best project structure to release android library project with sample app and documentation?

Tags: android, eclipse, git, github, android-library

I am about to open source android library project and wonder about what are the best practices how to release it on the github in structure way. Currently both are separate projects in local workspace (one library and other app project using it as library). I came across two approaches

Release both library + sample app + metadata within the same repo.
Release library and sample app as different repos

I wonder what is the local structure (on eclipse, on folder base) to use first approach combining app + library on same repo.

Edit : Library here https://github.com/burakdd/windigo

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really an opinion. Everyone will tell you something different. I would look at your application and try to split it up into it's major components. If you want to put two projects in your repo just make sure that the two project folders (outside of eclipse) are in the same folder as the git repository. You will have to reimport the one that you moved back into eclipse, but they will still be two separate projects.

Comment: Hmm, I thought there will be a way to structure them inside eclipse with source folders etc. I think the only way is to put them inside same folder as you said.

Comment: Yeah, they are probably separate projects, so I would keep them separate, just in the same parent folder.

Comment: Thank seems like this is the way to go. Currently located here. https://github.com/burakdd/windigo